# Finding local extrema of $f(x,y,z)$

Tags: calculus

$$f(x,y,z) = x\cdot y\cdot \left ( x-y-2 \right )$$
How can I find all the local maxima, local minima, and saddle points of the
function?I tried but I only found one point.

Comment: Deriviate it by x and y.

Comment: Perhaps you are forgetting about the various ways $x$ and/or $y$ can be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x,y,z) = x y  ( x-y-2 ) $$
Differentiating by $x$ and $y,$
$$
\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=y  ( x-y-2 )+x y =2xy-y^2-2y \\
\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=x  ( x-y-2 )-x y =x^2-2xy-2x
$$
Then, putting $\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=0, \;\; \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=0$ we have system of equations for finding stationary points
$$\begin{cases}2xy-y^2-2y =0, \\
 x^2-2xy-2x=0.
\end{cases} \tag{*}$$
Next check positive or negative definiteness of $d^2{f}$ at that points.

Comment: I found (0,0) and (3/2,1),are they correct?

Comment: One of points is correct.  I found following solutions: $(0,\,0),\;\;\left(\dfrac{2}{3},\,-\dfrac{2}{3}\right),\;\;(0,\,-2),\;\;(2,\,0)$